# Specifying Native Messaging Host for Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I am using native messaging API in Chrome extension, and I want to ship the native application within my extension.

In Windows, I add a registry key under **HKLM\SOFTWARE\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts**. Since my application is inside the extension folder after installed, I reference the full path by "**%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\...\....json**". But in this way, my extension complains "Specified native messaging host not found.".

If I expand the **%LOCALAPPDATA%** and write the path as "**C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\...\....json**", then my extension can successfully communicate with the host.

I wonder if this is an intended behavior? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no expansion of environment variables in the [current Chromium code](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/browser/extensions/api/messaging/native_process_launcher_win.cc&l=48). It sounds like a reasonable feature request, though there might be security reasons not to do it. If you [file a bug](http://crbug.com/new), we'll have a look and see whether it's feasible.

Comment: Thank you, I think adding this feature will be helpful for developers using native messaging. I will fire a bug for this.

Comment: @Jun can You please share the link to the bug? What is the status of this feature request now?

Comment: Here is the [link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=321628) to the bug. But it's marked as WontFix.